# Proxmox: Is it possible to create logical containers and place VM's under them for better visibility?

Tags: linux, proxmox

I have around 50 servers in my Proxmox server which are running on a cluster of 8 Proxmox hosts.

I'd like to create a logical container which is called for example "Product 1" and place all the relevant VM's under this logical container.

Is that possible? I couldn't find the answer online.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, these are called pools. Create one at the datacenter level of the interface.

Pools can also be assigned access control, where a group of users has a role only on that pool. This could allow, say, QA to administer the test VMs.

https://pve.proxmox.com/wiki/User_Management